# How do I start a virtual machine in background upon OSX system start?

Tags: osx, virtualbox, startup

I have a virtualbox machine on a OSX 10.9.2 host. I do not want to open VirtualBox every time and start the machine there. Also, I do not need the the screen output, as I will just ssh from the OSX terminal anyway.

How to start the virtual machine in headless mode on system start?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

VirtualBox comes with a series of command line tools all prefixed with *VBox*. The command you are looking for is

```
VBoxHeadless --startvm "my vm name"
```

You can see a short description of its options via `VBoxHeadless --help`.

If you don't know the name of the virtual machine you can find out via:

```
VBoxManage list vms
```

To to run upon startup on Mac OS X you can use the *Automator* application.

In the *Automator* App, select the *Run Shell Script* from the list and type the script:

[image: How to add the shell script within the automator app]

After saving the service, import it from `System Preferences` > `Users & Groups` > `TheLoginUser` > `Login Items` > `Import the service above`.

Answer (score 5):

You can create the service without any additional apps

Open Terminal,

1 Create a file by writing

```
touch vm.command
```

2. Edit the file

```
vi vm.command
```

3. Press "i" button, then enter the following lines:

```
VBoxHeadless --startvm vmname
```

(make sure you've replaced "vmname" with actual name)

4.save the file by pressing Esc button, then typing `:wq`

5.allow it to run:

```
sudo chmod +x vm.command
```

7.Copy the vm.command file to Application folder

8.Now you can enable it with System Preferences > Users & Groups > TheLoginUser > Login Items > Import the service above

Answer (score 2):

As for me `nohup` is essential:

```
$ nohup VBoxHeadless --startvm "xnode" > /dev/null &
```